# Filtering AC Control Signals

Tags: ac, filter, control, emc

I'm having a problem with odd noises in my guitar amp and I'm really struggling to find anything online.
Here's a sample of the noise:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7ggll3q6219l0o/Noise.mp3?dl=0

I've checked and the frequency is 1350hz with harmonics at 4050Hz and I guess at 2700Hz too. This appears to be something I've found to be a "ripple control signal" (German: Rundsteuersignal) which is normally quite a bit lower in other regions but in Cologne it's 1350Hz.

I did try one of these: https://www.conrad.de/de/p/ehmann-0463x0000-zwischensteckdose-weiss-431858.html
However the filtering starts too high and does nothing to help my situation.

Does anyone know of a way to filter out this modulation? Is there some kind of adaptor I can stick in the socket that will get rid of this?

Comment: What about this?: https://www.raeng.org.uk/publications/other/ac-signal-filtering
Could I just build a little electronics enclosure?

Comment: Or something like this?: https://www.ebay.de/itm/Power-Line-Filter-CORCOM-F4025A-Netzfilter-Entstorfilter-10A-250V-EMV-fur-Hi-Fi/313061925462?hash=item48e3f1e256:g:l3AAAOSwUGFeIJnk

Comment: Would a ferrite ring have any effect on AC signals?

Comment: I have to have more data to even start helping you. Does this happen without the guitar connected, or when you connect the guitar? if so what are your settings. Make and Model # of the amp too so we can pull a schematic up.

Comment: Hello David, this was recorded using a Line 6 Pod XT Live, although it seems to be independent of amp as it happens when using a VST Amp modeller when plugged into the computer directly.

This happens without the guitar connected as well, stops if I unplug from the amp, but I presume that's to do with it being muted if there's nothing connected.

These signals happen at rather round times, half past or on the hour, a few times at each of them. Might not happen for an hour or two or might be more often.

Comment: The amp settings aren't incredibly important, only that they're high gain tones. There is noise present in the signal, which can be solved with a noise gate, however these ripple control signals are too high in volume and can be heard over the actual guitar signal.

Comment: Its probably a pedal gone awry. or the combination is making one oscillate. Coupling methods and impedance are not standardized across all pedals. That is why some pros sought people like me out at times to work thing things out. What you going to do is have to find out in your setup what is causing it. It very rare to have that happen to an amp and the FX section and the external FX loop is the first culprit to look at.